# Async promises with delay in between starts

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I need to build several packages on Jenkins, using Webpack. In my build-script, I use the following:

```
const builds = [];
packages.forEach(p => builds.push(buildWeb(p).catch(error => console.log(error))));
await Promise.all(builds);
```

For each package, a promise gets executed in order to build it. However, `Promise.all` executes all the promises at once, causing a memory heap overflow. I tried executing them one by one, which works fine, but my colleagues asked to implement the following:

Start the first promise, wait for 10 seconds, and start running the second one asynchronously, wait again for 10 seconds to start running the third one, and so on...

I've tried it with `setTimeout`, but couldn't get it to work.

Is there a wait to execute dynamic promises with a delay between the start of each one?

Comment: I'd guess you're staggering when `.then` gets called but *not* when you actually start the promisified process, but please give a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to wrap `setTimeout` into a promise itself and use `async/await` inside a for loop. Here's an example:

```
const delay = (duration) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), duration);
    });
}

const main = async () => {
    const builds = [];

    for (let p of packages) {
        builds.push(buildWeb(p).catch(error => console.log(error)))
        await delay(10000); // Wait for 10 seconds
    }

    await Promise.all(builds);    
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: You sir, are a hero. So simple, yet I couldn't get to the solution. The promises are being executed just the way I wanted now!

Answer (score -2):

Checkout the [`p-fun`](https://github.com/Kladdkaka/p-fun) libraries. There are many useful packages. Specifically, you may be interested in `p-map` or `p-queue`.